# Can Numbers save a file as CSV?

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm trying to switch over from Excel to Numbers. Is it possible to save a file as a CSV in Numbers?

The whole idea behind this is I prefer to have my documents on the cloud as well as on Numbers for my iPad and iPhone. I do not do typical data sheets, I manage database files so I do not need any features, I just need to be able to work with CSV files.

Comment: You had two distinct questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: @DanielL Understood, sorry 'bout that...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Numbers can export CSV files.

Go to **File** » **Export** and click the CSV tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Saving out and reading in CSV is simple for Numbers. (And perchance you should wonder, the autocorrect runs from the system service, so turning that off will disable that as well for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't save your projects as csv but you can export to csv. Which is kinda the same thing.

Regarding autocorrecting numbers, I'm not entirely sure what that means in your context but if the cell text format is the correct one it'll leave them alone.